# simple search algorithm in excel spread sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table full of wights, first cells in rows are prices and columns header is numbers from 1 to 10 .. something like this:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  ..
1$ 1g 9g 7g

2$ 4g 6g 8g 0g 0g 3g

3$ 4g 6g 8g 0g 0g 3g

4$ 4g 6g 8g 0g 0g 3g

.
.
```

I need to write a small algorithm in this sheet in excel that takes 2 params (param1,param2)
param1 to filter some columns and param 2 to filter some rows and then pick the appropriate weight needed.. I am not asking about the algorithm, but I am asking how can I do it in  in excel, my office skills are none existed, so if I need macro, could u please give me a good link that explains macro instructions read ranges of cells and things like that ..

Answer (score 1):

You do not need VBA but can use a formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$G$5,MATCH(H6,INDEX(A2:A5,1,),0),MATCH(I6,INDEX(B1:H1,1,),0))
```

The `INDEX` function will take inputs of `INDEX(Range, row, column)` and return the value. So we want to find the input row and column, which are done through `MATCH`.

```
MATCH(H6,INDEX(A2:A5,1,),0)
```

Looks for the value contained in `H6` and gives the index in the range `A2:A5.` So, if the value contained in `H6` is `3$` this function will return 3, indicating your target value is in the third row.

Similarly, for the following

```
MATCH(I6,INDEX(B1:H1,1,),0)
```

You are looking for a value in `I6` but now searching the column headings. So if `I6` = 4 this will return the value 4 (because it is the fourth column).

Putting it together, you now have a function which is

```
=INDEX($B$2:$G$5, 3, 4)
```

which gives you the value in Row = 3 and Column = 4 from your table, given by `$B$2:$G$5`, or your lokup value.

Comment: the problem is the values sometimes need to be additions of different columns or rows to satisfy the need like for example, For columns a value like 15 does not exists in the columns (since they are 1-10) so the code must use multiple columns to satisfy the need

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty all encompassing link for getting started on macros: http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/getstarted.htm

if your process is going to be very conditional it would probably be better to make a macro and knowing how to write macros would be a very valuable skill to have.

Once you try some things out and write a little code, you can post it on here and we can help you in areas where it doesn't work, or if you can't figure out how to get started in an area you can ask another appropriate question.